# Magento2 admin after login redirect back to admin login?

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, magento-2.1, admin-login

In my magento2.1 installation when put user name and password and submit, the page redirect back to login page. Cleared cache, re indexed, and deployed the static contents as well. But nothing works. Project folder has 777 permissions. Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: plz show any error are display in login page?

Comment: No errors, It just redirect to login again. When check via firebug i can see a 302 Found error for xxxxx/admin/admin/index/index/57954.....435re45

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same thing after an upgrade to 2.1 - go to log into the admin area and just get redirected back to the log on page without any errors...

Comment: I had the same issue with Magento 2.1.3, *clearing the browser cookie* solved this problem. Ref: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/22382/49204

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to Developer Mode and then back to Production Mode.

Fixed the problem for us.

Answer (score 0):

Check your system and database timezones.